# Any way of running EfficientDet from the TF Object Detection API inference on a batch of images instead of 1?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorflow-model-garden

I have managed to download the object detection API from the model garden (Tensorflow 2.0, the Object Detection API ). All the inference code I could find (in the directory & online) works on a batch size of 1.

I was thinking about reconfiguring the *pipeline.config* file somehow. More specifically eval_config (batch_size = 5). Can this be done?

It is baffling to me how further training/finetuning is supported with a variable batch size... but inference isn't ?

Thanks for any tips you may be able to give.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code you are referring to, or can you please edit your post to include the code you wish to modify to perform inference on?

Comment: Uploaded an answer to this... I hope it helps! I'm really new to this !

Answer (score 4):

**Ok so after a lot of tinkering with the code, this is my answer to my own question:**

Starting from a simple source of pre-trained models:

*1.* The TF HUB repo of models gives you many different Object detection models. I specifically wanted to use the EffifcientDet architecture.

For example: https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/d2/1..

These models do NOT SUPPORT BATCHING images for inference. You can see that in the `Inputs` section.

`A three-channel image of variable size - the model does NOT support batching. The input tensor is a tf.uint8 tensor with shape [1, height, width, 3] with values in [0, 255].`
This is a deal-breaker. So I tried to search for a solution!

*2.* Many of these Object Detection COCO models are part of the `Object Detection API`. It says so in the `Source` section at the end of the page.

`The model's checkpoints are publicly available as a part of TensorFlow Object Detection API.`

The link takes you to the repo
`https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection`

*3.* So that means I had to do some tinkering in the Object Detection API code. At this point I was confused as to why the models did not support batch inference, when they have been trained on batches of images. This is when I originally posted my question.

This is the link to the latest models trained on COCO
`https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md`

*4.* By downloading a model from here (e.g. EfficientDet D2 768x768), and extracting the contents, you can see that both the protobuf `saved_model` format and the checkpoint data is given.
The protobuf model has a signature of `[1,None,None ,3]` which is no good ! This means that we can only operate on 1 image with a variable width/height  in RGB space. But what we require is an input signature of `[None,None,None,3]`.

*5.* So finally in order to do that we need to use the `exporter_main_v2.py` file ! This file takes in as arguments the checkpoint of the model you want to export in proto format ('saved_model'). However by default the input signature is set to `[1,NONE,NONE,3]`.

*6.* The way to get around that is to make changes to the files that are used by `exporter_main_v2.py`. In `exporter_lib_v2.py` we need to change a couple of lines of code
from `tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, None, None, 3]` to
`tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, None, None, 3]`.

I found a pull request on the github repo at:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/9228/commits/b2a6712cbe6eb9a8639f01906e187fa265f3f48e
This summarizes the changes quite well !

I tried this with a few different EffifcientDet models and it worked great! I do not know however if this is going to work for other models ! beware!

Thanks everyone... this was a long one but I thought it would be good to explain my 'journey' and reasoning to reach this solution.

Comment: I tried the similar use case for one of the masak rcnn model. When I try to run the inferencing with tf serving with --enable-batch parameter, I get the below error.

```
Batched output tensor's 0th dimension does not equal the sum of the 0th dimension sizes of the input tensors
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pipeline.config supports batch_size in eval_config and it should look like,

```
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size:5
}
```

You can check which parameters are supported in pipeline.config by looking at  [the protos](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/protos). In this case, you can see that batch_size is specified in [eval.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/eval.proto#L8).

I also confirmed that batch_size is used in the Tensorflow Object Detection API [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/2c93076c50d393e6d414166de78512757298efd0/research/object_detection/inputs.py#L929-L1068). I have seen one example of a proto that is specified but then not actually used.

Comment: I provided an answer.... after a lot of searching/desperation.... !
Please have a look if interested !